# Deleting from a Content Editable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/57vsyrsu/)

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is an editable paragraph.</p>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
    </figure>
 <p>This is an editable paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Im messing around with a content editable div.

Inside i have an image, which sits inside a figure tag.

Upon highlighting the image and pressing delete on my keyboard, the image gets deleted, but the figure tag stays behind.

How would I also delete the figure tag alongside the image when I highlight the image?

Would I need tome sort of JS trickery or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The figure tag was removed when I tested it out in your fiddle - I was able to delete it when I deleted the image.

Comment: @NickZ I think the point is that the OP is saying he doesn't want to have to hit delete twice; once for the image and once for the `<figure>` parent element.

Comment: Thats correct - I do not want to have to hit delete twice

Comment: The figure element does get deleted on my computer. The HTML5 spec says elements should be able to be deleted, so I don't see why your browser won't let you do that. Check if any CSS or JS is interfering with your HTML.

Comment: William - how many times do you press delete? I want to be able to highlight the image, hit delete and then remove the image and figure.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `keydown` event , `setTimeout` , `.is()` , `.remove()`

```
$("div[contenteditable]").on("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 8) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$("figure img", e.target).is("*")) {
                $("figure", e.target).remove()
            }
        })
    }
})
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/57vsyrsu/1/)

`setTimeout` provides minimal delay for img to be removed from DOM following backspace keydown event . `!$("figure img", e.target).is("*")` returns Boolean indicating whether figure element contains img element or not ; context is set to `div[contenteditable]` at selector . If figure element does not contain img element , remove figure element.

Comment: Thanks, any chance of a bit more explanation about what the time out is for and whats going on inside it?

Comment: @panthro `setTimeout` provides minimal delay for `img` to be removed from `DOM` following backspace `keydown` event . `!$("figure img", e.target).is("*")` returns `Boolean` indicating whether `figure` element contains `img` element or not ; `context` is set to `div[contenteditable]` at selector . If `figure` element does not contain `img` element , remove `figure` element.

Comment: I tried removing the timeout and inspecting the div, I still get the same result with or without the timeout - the figure is removed. Am I missing something?

Comment: @panthro _"tried removing the timeout and inspecting the div, I still get the same result with or without the timeout - the figure is removed."_ Can create jsfiddle to demonstrate ? If expected result is returned without using `setTimeout` , could remove `setTimeout` ; remainder of `js` should return same results .

Answer (score 0):

contenteditable traverses the DOM as you delete

As you press backspace:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is an editable paragraph.</p>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
    </figure>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

then

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is an editable paragraph.</p>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
    </figure>
</div>
```

then

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is an editable paragraph.</p>
    <figure>
    </figure>
</div>
```

then

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is an editable paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

then

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

This is the same behavior as any other user editable "thing" in HTML5. It has to do with how the DOM is parsed. It's really the expected behavior.

There is no way to delete the figure along with the img without using JavaScript. guest271314 provides a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code but then you cannot undo your changing

```js
function listener(evt) {
if(evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase()=="img"){
    var parent= evt.target.parentNode
 if(parent.tagName.toLowerCase()=="figure")
         parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent)
 } 
}
   document.getElementsByTagName("figure")[0].addEventListener("DOMNodeRemoved", listener, false);
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">

    <p>This is an editable paragraph.</p>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg">
    </figure>
 <p>This is an editable paragraph.</p>
</div>
```